# What type of testing am I performing?

Tags: performance, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I am performing a unit test which basically tests the time performance of a call to the database, and retrieving data.
Now I have made test as a UnitTest, but I am fairly sure it is not a unit test, since in short it just tracks the time from the function call, until it returns data. What type of test would this be, when not unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a performance test if it only does the call once to record the latency. Real performance tests do such a call multiple times and report statistics like the mean latency and/or various percentiles.

It is also not a unit test by the [common definition](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923) since it touches a database.

Integration tests excercise certain use cases with some dependencies that you would usually mock in unit tests, like the database. But integration test check for functional behavior, not timing.

Therefore I would call your test a "one-off timing test"

> ...I have made test as a UnitTest...

What you mean with this is probably that you used a common "unit testing" framework to implement the test. This does not make it a unit test. You can totally implement integration and acceptance tests with a unit testing framework and unit tests with an acceptance test framework.